# Could not understand the reason behind the output

Tags: python

I am quite new to python and could not get this

Consider the following program i have written:

```
def value_updating(value,list_value):
    value = value+28
    list_value.append(120)

def main():
   value = 15
   list_value = [60,90,100]
   value_updating(value,list_value)
   print(value,list_value)
```

I was expecting the output to be `43` and `[60,90,100,120]`.
But the answer given by the interpreter is `15` and `[60,90,100,120]`.
Can any one explain this to me?

Comment: Works as coded. What's the issue? Why are you expecting wrong output?

Comment: hint: variable scope

Comment: As @MarcinOrlowsky mentioned, the problem is your variable scope for `value`. Consider returning `value` and setting it to that value in the calling function.

Comment: Both the integer and list are local variables to the function.But the list got edited as it is mutable.Correct me if i am wrong Martin.
Thanks BTW

Answer (score 1):

it's because when you pass to the function the value that in the main scope is 15, inside there function the is a different value variable in the scope that change to 43 but it's not returning to the main value scope since then when you `print(value,list_value)` it's printing the value of value variable in the main scope 15.
The fix for that will be

```
def value_updating(value,list_value):
    value = value+28
    list_value.append(120)
    return value 

def main():
   value = 15
   list_value = [60,90,100]
   value = value_updating(value,list_value)
   print(value,list_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because Python functions are *pass-by-object-reference*.

This means that *mutable* objects are passed-by-reference, but *immutable* objects are pass-by-value. So `value` inside your function is a new version of `value` outside (i.e. different pointers and different objects in memory), but `list_value` points to the same object both inside and out.

The following are immutable in Python:

- bool
- int
- float
- tuple
- str
- frozenset

All other variables will be mutable and thus pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 0):

Just take out 'print' outside the function.

```
def value_updating(value,list_value):
    value = value+28
    list_value.append(120)

def main():
   value = 15
   list_value = [60,90,100]
   value_updating(value,list_value)
print(value,list_value)
```